# why does header only moves when scroll up and down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

this is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

body
    {
    background: #edeff8 url(sidebar.left.bg.gif) top left repeat-y;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    /* IE 6.0 Addition */
    height: 100%;
    }

/* IE requires the position to be absolute otherwise the div will render below */
/* the mainContainer div on the page and not under it in the z axis            */
#bg
    {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(sidebar.left.bg.gif);

    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    /* IE 6.0 requires the -1 z-index so that the bg will render behind the scroll bar */
    z-index: -1;
    }

body > #bg
    {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }

#mainContainer
    {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 960px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    }

#header
        {
        background-color: #0000ac;
        background-image: url(header.bg.jpg);
        background-position: top;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        }

#centerRightColumnContainer
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }

#centerRightColumnPositioner
    {
    margin-left: 190px; /* To fit the left side bar */
    padding: 0;
    }

#sideBarLeft
    {
    float: left;
    width: 190px; /* Total width: 190px - padding *2 = 170px; */
    /*margin-left: -100%;*/
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color : maroon;
    }

#centerColumnContainer
    {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color : black;
    }

#centerColumn
    {
    /* margin-right: 260px; */
    padding: 10px;
    }


/*
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * NBI Layout/Design styles
 */

body
        {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 17px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

h1, h2, h4
        {
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        }

h1
    {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    }

h4 a, h4 a:visited
        {
        color: #d9dcec;
        }

h4 a:hover
        {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

h2
        {
        font-size: 18px;
        }

p
        {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

.clear_both
        {
        clear: both;
        }

.code
    {
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    }

#w3cButtons
    {
    width: 196px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    }

#markupBtn
    {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 88px;
    float: left;
    }

#cssBtn
    {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 88px;
    float: left;
    }



/* IE 6.0: For some reason, if you just specify padding here it'll add 10 px  */
/* to the entire layout and cause the page to scroll horizontally. So we have */
/* to specify the width and then set a margin on it.  The width is equal to   */
/* the width of the column, 190px - the 10px margin * 2                       */
#sideBarLeft p
    {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 170px;
    }

/* We need to shave off a pixel from the width of the ul.  This then renders */
/* list inside this columns bg image.                                        */
#sideBarLeft ul
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: #978e7c 1px solid;
    width: 189px;
    }

/* IE fix for additional padding that otherwise get's rendered between list items */
#sideBarLeft ul li
    {
    height: 1%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

#rightColumnBg > #sideBarLeft
    {
    height: auto;
    }

#sideBarLeft ul li a, #sideBarLeft ul li a:visited
    {
    display: block;
    border-top: #978e7c 1px solid;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-image: url(sidenav.bg.gif);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color: #fffbf7;
    color: #59503e;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

#sideBarLeft ul li a:hover
    {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

</style>

<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
/* If we are using IE 7 we must override our position attribute for our #bg div */
body > #bg
    {
    position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And here's the javascript :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function resize_bg_div(){
        // This function will determine which of the three columns or the window.height
        // is the largest and then set the bg div to be that height.

        // This assumes that any div markup that is above our columns is wrapped
        // in a single div with the id=header
        var var_bg_offset = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;

        // First we create an array and add to it the heights of each of the three columns
        // and the window height
        array_colHeights = new Array( );
        array_colHeights.push( document.getElementById("sideBarLeft").offsetHeight );
        array_colHeights.push( document.getElementById("centerColumn").offsetHeight );

        // Instead of the raw window.innerHeight we need to take into account the offset size
        // of our header divs
        array_colHeights.push( window.innerHeight - var_bg_offset );

        // Sorting our array in descending order
        array_colHeights.sort( function( a, b ){ } );

        // Now we'll set our bg div to the height of our largest div or window height
        document.getElementById('bg').style.height = array_colHeights[0] + "px";
        delete array_colHeights;
        delete var_bg_offset;
}


window.onload = resize_bg_div;
window.onresize = resize_bg_div;

</script>
```

finally the HTML :

```
<div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="header">

                    <h4>By: <a href="#" target="_blank">Ryan Chapin</a></h4>
            </div>

            <!-- The conainter divs for the center and the right columns -->
            <div id="centerRightColumnContainer">

                <div id="centerRightColumnPositioner">

                    <div id="centerColumnContainer">

                        <div id="centerColumn">

                            <p>If you are a practical web designer that is looking to use a fully compliant CSS layout that:</p>




                        </div>
                        <!-- centerColumn, END -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- centerColumnContainer, END -->

                </div>
                <!-- centerRightColumnPositioner, END -->

            </div>
            <!-- centerRightColumnContainer, END -->


            <!-- The left column div -->
            <div id="sideBarLeft">


                <p>This is some sample text to go in the side bar</p>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Open Source</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>


            </div>
            <!-- sideBarLeft, END -->

</div>
<!-- mainContainer, END -->
```

Now the problem is that when i resize the browser and move the scroll bar (y-axis) my header moves upwards and it will leave a white div-like portion on top of my other containers. how to fix this so that when i minimize my browser the header never animates like that. Here a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejay/LdQ22/)

Comment: a JS fiddle or CodePen usually helps :) http://jsfiddle.net/JxctP/

Comment: @Stuart uhm.. the y-axis scroll is gone. i still want to have it when my browser is minimized.